# Iptables rules - white list ips

Tags: iptables

My centos server has an iptables rule.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

this code is doing the work like firewall but I don't want to block of my server ips.

my server ips:

"127.0.0.1", "my server ip1", "my server ip2", etc.

How do I get them out of this ip tables rule?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `-m iprange --src-range .....`

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
# Loopback
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Repeat for each SERVER_IP
iptables -I INPUT -s SERVER_IP -j ACCEPT
```

Note that this will open everything for SERVER_IPs. YMMV depending on want you want to allow.

For instance, if you just want to open HTTP port for those IPs :

```
# Loopback
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Repeat for each SERVER_IP
iptables -I INPUT -s SERVER_IP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```